# On firefox behind corporate proxy, intercepting on WebGoat using burp Suite error

Tags: proxy, firefox

i'm following a tutorial on hacking web application WebGoat using burp suite
I've downloaded webGoat which now runs on port 8080, set up burp suit and the browser connection as in the pictures, but cannot access webGoat to intercept on it, what am i dong wrong?

[image: target scope]
[image: proxy options]
[image: options connection]
[image: Connection settings]
[image: opening webGoat]

Comment: Can you access other URLs? Eg: https://google.com

Comment: yes. i can access all websites, anything but localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i have configured Burp to send all  traffic to my corporate proxy, including the traffic intended for localhost:8080. Obviously, the corporate proxy won’t handle this traffic in the way that i need.

i fixed my Burp configuration by adding another upstream proxy rule for the destination host “localhost” and leaving the proxy host blank. This will tell Burp to connect directly to “localhost”.  placed this rule at the top of the list, before the current rule for the corporate proxy